# Access denied when building esp-idf-sys for Rust project for ESP32 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, rust, esp32

I'm attempting to set up this Rust template project to get started doing Rust development for ESP32: https://github.com/esp-rs/esp-idf-template

I've installed the Rustup esp toolchain, as described here: https://github.com/esp-rs/rust-build

At the **Generate the Project** step, I chose these parameters:

- Configure project to use Dev Containers = false
- ESP-IDF native build version = v4.4
- Rust toolchain = esp
- STD Support = true
- MCU = esp32

At the **Build** step, I get this output (second run displayed, first run compiles a long list of dependencies before this point):

```
C:\Users\Me\boop\doop>cargo build
   Compiling esp-idf-sys v0.31.6
error: failed to run custom build command for `esp-idf-sys v0.31.6`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\target\debug\build\esp-idf-sys-cafd80a349bfdbb2\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=IDF_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ESP_IDF_TOOLS_INSTALL_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ESP_IDF_VERSION
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ESP_IDF_REPOSITORY
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ESP_IDF_SDKCONFIG_DEFAULTS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ESP_IDF_SDKCONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MCU
  IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH=C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.10_env
  PATH=C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\tools\esp32ulp-elf\2.28.51-esp-20191205\esp32ulp-elf-binutils\bin;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\tools\cmake\3.23.1\bin;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\tools\ninja\1.10.2\;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.10_env\Scripts;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\esp-idf\release-v4.4\tools;%PATH%
  Current system platform: win64
  Skipping xtensa-esp32-elf@esp-2021r2-patch3-8.4.0 (already installed)
  Skipping cmake@3.23.1 (already installed)
  Skipping ninja@1.10.2 (already installed)
  Skipping esp32ulp-elf@2.28.51-esp-20191205 (already installed)
  IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH=C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.10_env
  PATH=C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\tools\esp32ulp-elf\2.28.51-esp-20191205\esp32ulp-elf-binutils\bin;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\tools\cmake\3.23.1\bin;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\tools\ninja\1.10.2\;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.10_env\Scripts;C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\esp-idf\release-v4.4\tools;%PATH%

  --- stderr
  Using managed esp-idf repository: EspIdfRemote { repo_url: None, git_ref: Branch("release/v4.4") }
  fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
  Using esp-idf v4.4.1 at 'C:\Users\Me\boop\doop\.embuild\espressif\esp-idf\release-v4.4'
  fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
  Error: Access is denied. (os error 5)
```

I get the same error when I choose ESP-IDF native build version = v4.3.2, although without the `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.` messages.

I get an identical error when attempting to build this Rust ESP32 demo project: https://github.com/ivmarkov/rust-esp32-std-demo

This was run as Administrator.

In my search for a solution, I found this: [Why os.rename sometimes returns error access is denied python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857779/why-os-rename-sometimes-returns-error-access-is-denied-python/55938363#55938363) Per the top answer, I disabled "Show frequently used folders in Quick access" in File explorer, but unfortunately the build error has not changed.

What access is being denied, and what could be causing the denial, even when run as Administrator?
Secondarily, what is the cause and meaning of the `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.` messages?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working through the same issue today.

It is caused by a change in the embuild dependency: https://github.com/esp-rs/embuild/commit/d8f8da228f1e1e6c105074d96617a8601092f633

Trying to write permission data to an open file causes the 'os error 5

I've submitted a PR to the project: https://github.com/esp-rs/embuild/pull/56

Now merged, cargo update and you should be good!